# Same computer WCF messages exchanges => TCP?

Tags: wcf, tcp, communication

I have some programs and WCF services running on a computer. I currently makes them comunicate using net.tcp binding (ipv4: 127.0.0.01, ipv6: ::1).

Is it the right choice? Or did I just miss another better (less protocol overhead?) option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running services and clients on same computer, net is the best option (read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx , but you can also consider net.pipes (read more here about the recomendations from each binding: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx)

> **NetNamedPipeBinding**
>
> A secure, reliable, optimized binding that is suitable for on-machine
>   communication between WCF applications.

This link also has an interesting benchmark test using both Tcp and Pipe bindings: http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2006/01/WCF-Relative-Binding-Speeds
The results are interesting:

> **NetTcpBinding**: Processed 39957 calls in 10 seconds
>   **NetNamedPipeBinding**: Processed 48255 calls in 10 seconds

Hope it helps.